# API POST request returns 404 route not found

Tags: ruby, api, post, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

`Rails 5.2.2.1`
`ruby 2.6.3p62`

I'm writing an API endpoint that should accept a post request. I created the route:

```
namespace :api do
   scope module: :v1, constraints: Example::ApiVersionConstraint.new(1) do
     resources 'books', only: [:create]
   end
 end
```

`bundle exec rails routes | grep books` returns:

`api_books POST   /api/books(.:format)         api/v1/books#create`

`app/controllers/api/v1/books_controller.rb`:

```
class Api::V1::BooksController < Api::BaseController
   attr_reader :book

   def create
      book = Book.build(title: 'test')

      if book.save
         render json: book
      else
         render json: { error: 'error' }, status: 400
      end
   end
end
```

server is running on port 3000 and when submitting a POST request to `http://localhost:3000/api/books.json` using Postman I get this response:

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "code": "routing.not_found",
        "status": 404,
        "title": "Not found",
        "message": "The path '/api/books' does not exist."
    }
],
"request": ""
}
```

`lib/example/api_version_constraint.rb`:

```
module Example
  class ApiVersionConstraint

     def initialize(version)
        @version = version
     end

     def matches?(request)
        request.headers.fetch(:accept).include?("version=#{@version}")
     rescue KeyError
        false
     end
   end
end
```

why isn't the request finding the route?

Comment: Can you please post the restraints that are defined in `Example::ApiVersionConstraint`?

Comment: `constraints: Example::ApiVersionConstraint.new(1)` -- Presumably this is failing. But what does it do? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @NMPennypacker updated the question to include the apiversionconstraint file

Comment: that was the issue. thank you for your help. in the headers tab in postman i had to include the Accept with value version=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is likely failing in `ApiVersionConstraint`. To troubleshoot you can do something like:

```
 def matches?(request)
    byebug
    request.headers.fetch(:accept).include?("version=#{@version}")
 rescue KeyError
    false
 end
```

Guessing it's a problem with how you're targeting the header, so something like this might work:

```
request&.headers&.fetch("Accept")&.include?("version=#{@version}")
```

Because you have a `rescue` clause, you'll never get the full error; only `false`, so you might try removing that and seeing if you get a more descriptive error.

Comment: that was the issue. thank you for your help. in the headers tab in postman i had to include the Accept with value version=1